# Excel Pivot Data model measures sum

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Hello I have in Excel 365 the following data model (Access bindet in the excel data model).

| Date | Customer | Currency | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/02/01 | Customer1 | 10,53 |  |
| 2023/02/05 | Customer3 | -125,38 |  |
| 2023/03/11 | Customer2 | -501,23 |  |
| 2023/01/25 | Customer1 | 1,25 |  |
| 2023/01/10 | Customer2 | 354,21 |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |

There are more columns but I think so discuss my problem it's enough.

Now I want a pivot table and a pivot diagram with the following structure.

| Month | Incoming payment | Outgoing payment | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 355,46 | 0 | 355,46 |
| Feb | 10,53 | 125,38 | -114,85 |
| Mar | 0 | 501,23 | -501,23 |

As you see I want the outgoing positiv too! And important because of the data model I cant use calculated field or element in the pivot table directly.

I will filter the pivot with slice, f.e. year, customer,...

I tried too use measures f.e. sum but it doen't fit.
I know I can show a result column for the pivot table but this doesn't help for the diagram.

I found this questions but it doesn't help me:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394124/custom-column-in-a-pivot-table-from-the-data-model-in-excel](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create 3 simple measures:

```
Balance :=
0 + SUM( Table1[Currency] )

Incoming Payment :=
CALCULATE(
    [Balance],
    Table1[Currency] >= 0
)

Outgoing Payment :=
- CALCULATE(
    [Balance],
    Table1[Currency] < 0
)
```